# Oneplus Internal Storage not accessible

Tags: adb, internal-storage, data-recovery, system-error, oneplus

Since this morning after powering up my Oneplus 6 I'm unable to see any data in my phone via gallery or file manager or any application, and I'm unable to save any data to internal storage. (example: I'm able to use whatsapp for texting, but I can't receive/send any audio/picture and I can't access the old ones).

And I keep getting this error message:"com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication keeps stopping."

I don't know if that's what causing it or if that's just a consequence of not being able to access internal storage.

I can still see all the used storage from settings though.

Phone has unlocked bootloader, but no root.

I see other Oneplus users started getting the same error these days... (I have a Oneplus 6, but others have different models like Oneplus Nord).

I tried rebooting in safe mode, cleaning media and media.module packages from adb but no luck even if successful.Looks like the only remaining option is to reset the phone through recovery, but I wouldn't like to go through this and lose app data.

If anyone has any other suggestion on things to try, post it here please.

Comment: `com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication` is the central database that maps the files to their file location. Since Android 11 it is the only way for regular apps to access shared files. If it encounters a media file it can not process correctly (e.g. crashes while processing it) you can end up in such a situation. You can regenerate the database by clearing the app data for the aforementioned system app. It will then be regenerated (depending on the number of files you have stored this can take minutes or hours.

Comment: Thank You for the comment @Robert!
I've already tried cleaning cleaning the media packages successfully through adb with 
"$ adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.media 
$ adb shell pm clear com.google.android.providers.media.module" but I still have the same issue... Is there a way to specifically clean "com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication"?

Comment: @alecxs I cannot install any apps since it's like I don't have any storage left at all, even if I try unistalling apps

Comment: *'adb reboot bootloader; fastboot boot twrp-3.6.1_11-0-enchilada.img'* (use screen lock pattern to decrypt) create backup and delete /data/data/com.android.providers.media

Comment: So is there no way to clear "com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication" app data directly from adb like Robert suggested?

Comment: you wrote you already did successfully - obviously that is not the cause. my suspect is broken encryption (you will figure out from recovery.log)

Comment: Hey @alecxs, I deleted /data/data/com.android.providers.media from Twrp as you told me last time but nothing changed... (I saw other users resolved with a wipe and all storage files were still there, I don't know if in broken encryption case it would be like that)
Also in my last comment I was asking about clearing "com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication" app data, while I already cleared "com.android.providers.media" data through adb, I don't think they are the same thing since they show up as two different system apps in settings... but dunno

Comment: yes my comment is about *com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication*, too. or whatever <pkgname> you want to clear (way to clear app data directly) I also said that probably wont solve your issue

Comment: The problem is that I can't find the MediaApplication package.. I just see media, that's why I asked how I could clear that one...

Comment: in TWRP have a look into */data/user_de/0* some apps store data there (instead */data/user/0 -> /data/data*) if no dir exist that means no app data exist

Comment: Hi @alecxs, I looked in both folder and I just found another providers.media folder but no providers.media.MediaApplication folder, I deleted both (the one in data/data and the one in user_de/0) but nothing changed. 
Also when I'm in recovery mode I can see all the files and even copy them from the pc, so I don't think the problem is broken encryption...
Do you have any other hint by any chance or my only option is to wipe data?

Comment: I have replied on xda-developers as it's more suitable for troubleshooting dialog. once you found solution you can come back here and post as answer

Comment: Hi @alecxs, I have an update for this on the xda thread [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/help-internal-storage-not-accessible-a-k-a-how-to-clear-com-android-providers-media-mediaapplication-data.4431743/
Hope you could check it out... 
Thank you in advance