# How to clean com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication App Data?

Tags: adb, internal-storage, data-recovery, storage, system-error

com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication keeps throwing errors on me and I cannot access internal storage on my Oneplus since this morning.

I've already tried cleaning the media packages successfully through adb with

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.media 
adb shell pm clear com.google.android.providers.media.module
```

but I still have the same issue...

I tried looking specifically for the MediaApplication package but it doesn't come up when I list packages with adb, even though it's marked as a system app in settings.

Is there a way to specifically clean "com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oneplus Internal Storage not accessible](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246152/oneplus-internal-storage-not-accessible)